# Nonce check is failing

Tags: wordpress, api, nonce

**EDITED WITH UPDATED CODE: STILL NO SOLUTION**

Can anyone spot the error in this code please?

**custom-page.php:**

```
<form name="customForm">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('code_check', 'codecheck'); ?>
                Validation Code:<br>
                <input type="password" name="inputcode" id="inputcode" maxlength="6" inputmode="numeric">
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" style="display:none; background-color: #FFCCCC;"><br>
                <input type="button" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" onClick="customfunction()">
                </form>
```

**custom.js:**

```
function customfunction() {
const userInput = document.addStamp.inputcode.value;
const token = document.addStamp.codecheck.value;
    fetch(`http://...../wp-json/api/v1/custom?code=${userInput}&token=${token}`).then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
......
```

**API file.php:**

```
public function custom($request)
    {
    $params = $request->get_params();
        $retrieved_nonce = $params[token];
        if($retrieved_nonce) {
            if (!wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce, 'code_check' ) ) die( 'Failed security check' );
        }
        ....
```

Everything works fine until I added in the nonce verify code to the api request.

Now when I click on "submit" button, it does not submit and I get in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0
```

So it is failing as "F" is point 0 of the failure message.

However, if I output "$retrieved_nonce" I actually get the nonce value as shown in my page source code, so it looks like it is getting to the endpoint?

I have tried logging out and back in but no change.

Do I have this code set up wrong?

Comment: This is really strange.  So as below, I have now included the nonce value in the endpoint fetch call.  I can then output the value and it matches the nonce value.  Yet, if I activate the !wp_verify_nonce check if always fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can try.

Form.

```
<form name="customForm" method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field('code_check', 'code_check'); ?>
Validation Code:<br>
<input type="password" name="inputcode" id="inputcode" maxlength="6" inputmode="numeric">
<input type="text" name="message" id="message" style="display:none; background-color: #FFCCCC;"><br>
<input type="button" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" onClick="customfunction()">
</form>
```

In customfunction function also send the wp_nonce_field  filed value like.

```
function customfunction() {
const userInput = document.customForm.inputcode.value;
const code_check = document.customForm.code_check.value;
    fetch('http://...../wp-json/api/v1/custom?code='+userInput+'&code_check'+code_check).then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
```

Now in validate the wp_nonce_field field value

```
public function custom($request)
        {
         $retrieved_nonce = $request['code_check'];
         if (!wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce, 'code_check' ) ) die( 'Failed 
          security check' );

         /***
         you can also try
        if ( isset( $request['code_check'] ) || wp_verify_nonce( $request['code_check'], 'code_check' ) )  
         *******/
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Same result I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried the same code It's working. how you submit the form?

Comment: The form does't 'really' submit.  When the user clicks the submit button, the entry in the inputcode field is used by the "function customfunction() {" which then sends it to my endpoint for processing/validation.


function customfunction() {

Comment: you are not sending the wp_verify_nonce field value in request. you only send input field value.

Comment: Hmmm, well I added const token = document.addStamp.code-check.value; to the js function and passed token in the fetch call.  In my endpoint I then added: $retrieved_nonce = $params[token];
  if (!wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce, 'code_check' ) ) die( 'Failed security check' );        Still same result.... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196897/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-shaun21uk).